# Why won't Pythagorean theorem work for me?

Tags: math, rectangles, angle, pythagorean

How do i check if the follow is a right angled triangle?

I have:

```
A = 5
B = 1
C = ?
```

How do i know if this IS or ISNT a right angle?

please help!

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming, and is unanswerable as stated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Triangle cannot be fully defined by only lengths of two sides.

However, you can say that if you had a triangle with sides *a* and *b*, in order for it to be a right angled triangle, it has  to hold true that c^2 = a^2 + b^2